# Mix stapel-function with magnific-popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I found 2 awesome jquery plugins in "Magnific Popup" and a special stapel-function "Adaptive Thumbnail Pile Effect with Automatic Grouping" and I thought with both together, I could make a pretty cool (responsive) portfolio with resizing lightbox.

But unfortunately they don't work together as I expected as you can see [here](http://marvin-online.de/test/check-2.html).

When you click on the top picture and open one of the 2 that appear, 
it will show up in a lightbox, but without the close-Button and title below the image. 
So you have to go back with the "browser-back-button" (not good).

When you click on one of the small pics on the bottom "without stapel function" the picture opens with the close-button and Title from "magnific popup". So here magnific pop up works fine. 
Now, I didn't find out why the magnific-popup close-button/title doesn't appear with the stapel function pics on the top.

As I'm not a JS pro, I can only guess that there might be a conflict between the two js-scripts, so I tried to add "jQuery.noConflict();" but it was just a guess and it didn't solve the problem.

I hope, someone has an idea.

This is the JS stuff in the HTML header:

```
<!-- Magnific Popup core CSS file -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css"> 

<!-- jQuery 1.7.2+ or Zepto.js 1.0+ -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

 <!-- Modernizr -->
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.63321.js"></script>

<!-- Magnific Popup core JS file -->
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script> 

<!-- external Stapel JS file  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.stapel.js"></script>

<!-- internal Stapel JS  -->    
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.noConflict();

$(function() {
    var $grid = $( '#tp-grid' ),
    $name = $( '#name' ),
    $close = $( '#close' ),
    $loader = $( '<div class="loader"><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><span>Loading...</span></div>' ).insertBefore( $grid ),
    stapel = $grid.stapel( {
    onLoad : function() {
    $loader.remove();
    },
    onBeforeOpen : function( pileName ) {
    $name.html( pileName );
    },
    onAfterOpen : function( pileName ) {
                        $close.show();
                    }
                } );

            $close.on( 'click', function() {
                $close.hide();
                $name.empty();
                stapel.closePile();
            } );

        } );
    </script>
```

This is JS for magnific-popup before closing body-Tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.popup').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image',
    closeOnContentClick: true,
    image: {
        verticalFit: false
    }
});

});

</script>
```

The magnific-popup is called by the class="popup" in the links (works fine here):

```
<a class="popup" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_b.jpg" title="This image fits only horizontally.">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8379/8588290361_ecf8c27021_s.jpg" height="75" width="75">
</a>

<a class="popup" href="http://www.marvin-online.de/test/images/print/large/logo-safework-1.jpg" title="Der Titel">  <img src="http://www.marvin-online.de/test/images/print/large/logo-safework-1.jpg" height="75" width="75"></a>
```

..and with those pictures it doesn't work:

```
<ul id="tp-grid" class="tp-grid">

<li data-pile="Logo">
    <a class="popup" href="http://www.marvin-online.de/test/images/print/large/visitenkartendesign-erbengemeinschaft.jpg">
<span class="tp-info"><span>Logo 1</span></span>
<img src="http://www.marvin-online.de/test/images/print/thumbs/visitenkartendesign-erbengemeinschaft.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>

<li data-pile="Logo">
    <a class="popup" href="http://www.marvin-online.de/test/images/print/large/logo-safework-1.jpg">
<span class="tp-info"><span>Logo 2</span></span>
<img src="http://www.marvin-online.de/test/images/print/thumbs/logo-safework-1.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I checked with Firefox webdeveloper an I noticed that the images within the "stapel-function processed" images got the following CSS classes when they open with magnific popup:

html > body > img.decoded

And the correctly opended images on the bottom got:

html.js.no-touch.cssanimations.csstransitions > body.mfp-zoom-out-cur > div.mfp-wrap.mfp-close-btn-in.mfp-ready > div.mfp-container.mfp-image-holder.mfp-s-ready > div.mfp-content > div.mfp-figure > img.mfp-img

How could I change all those classes in an opening image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution: just add the magnific plugin’s code inside Stapel’s “onAfterOpen” callback function. (Many thx to Andrew-David!)